# How do I use a foreign key to get a value from another list?

Tags: c#, blazor

I have 2 tables connected with a foreign key, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rooms] (
[Id]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Size]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Utilities] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

);

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Booking] (
[Id]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[RoomId]   INT           NOT NULL,
[Date]     DATE          NOT NULL,
[TimeFrom] TIME (7)      NOT NULL,
[TimeTo]   TIME (7)      NOT NULL,
[UserName] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Booking_RoomId] FOREIGN KEY ([RoomId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Rooms] ([Id])
);
```

How do I get the value from the name column from "Rooms" using the foreign key?
I've tried using ElementAt, like so:

```
@foreach (var booking in bookings)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@rooms.ElementAt(booking.RoomId).Name</td>
                    <td>@booking.Date</td>
                    <td>@booking.TimeFrom - @booking.TimeTo</td>
                    <td>@booking.UserName</td>
                </tr>
            }
```

but this doesn't work. If the RoomId column has the value 1, I get the name from the Rooms table where the Id is 2.

Comment: You have to do it before passing the data to the view. If you are using linq, would reccomend to, to get the data from your tables then a simple `.ThenInclude` will join the two tables together. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.theninclude?view=efcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

As Lith suggested, I changed my code from :

```
public async Task<List<Booking>> GetBookingsAsync()
{
    return await _context.Booking.ToListAsync();
}
```

to:

```
public async Task<List<Booking>> GetBookingsAsync()
{
    return await _context.Booking.Include(b => b.Room).ToListAsync();
}
```

which did the trick!